# Rails Infinite Scrolling with Kaminari Pagination and Ajax Filtering

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, pagination, kaminari

I am currently building a movie database application in Rails 3.2.
I hava an index page, which lists all the movies, which are paginated with the infinite-scrolling gem useing kaminari.
The infinite scrolling is working fine, now i have implemented a search form with help of the ransack gem. Filtering works fine, and so does the querying and rendering via ajax.

But once i am displaying filtered results, the infinite scrolling pagination doesn't work anymore.
In the rails console, you can see, that if you scroll down on the filtered results, it queries for the next results, but it doesn't render those properly.

I am sure its a small thing i am missing, but i can't figure out what, as i am somewhat new to rails.

Here is some code:

A Timeout-controlled Keyup Event makes an **ajax call**:

```
    $('#titleinput').keyup(function(){
    var value = this.value;
    $(this).doTimeout( 'typing', 250, function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: '/films',
            type: 'GET',
            data: {
                "q[title_cont]": value}
        })
    });
});
```

which sends a get request with the search query to the
**Index Action in the film_controller.rb**

```
 def index
@q = Film.search(params[:q])
unless params[:q].to_s.empty?
  @films = @q.result.page(params[:page]).per(26)
  respond_to do |format|
  format.js {render :partial => 'replace'}
  end
else
  @films = @q.result.page(params[:page]).per(26)
respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @films }
  format.js
end
end
end
```

rendering the
**the _replace.js.erb partial** when a search query is present

```
$("#films").html("<tbody class='page'><%= escape_javascript(render @films) %></tbody>");
```

which replaces the present #films table in the **index.html.erb**

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
<div class="headline">
  <h1>film listing</h1>
  <%= search_form_for(@q) do |f| %>
      <%= f.search_field :title_cont, {id: 'titleinput'} %>
  <%= f.submit %>
      <% end %>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <table id="films">
    <tbody class="page">
    <%= render @films %>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<%= paginate @films %>
```

the particular films are rendered through the **_film.html.erb** partial:

```
<% if cycle('odd', 'even') == 'odd' %>
    <tr onclick="location.href='<%= film_path(film) %>'" class="trodd film">
<% else %>
    <tr onclick="location.href='<%= film_path(film) %>'" class="treven film">
<% end %>
<td class="title"><%= film.title %></td>
<td class="dire">by     <%= film.get_realname_director %></td>
<td class="actr">starring     <%= film.get_realname_actor %></td>
```

I appreciate any help very much, thanks in advance!

Comment: did you find a solution? @Murmox